# Display image one by one

Tags: image, checkbox, display

I have a checkbox in my form that will display images when an item is checked .

Is it possible that the images will be displayed one by one every time an item is clicked because at the moment , every time I checked an item on the checkbox , it is displayed on the div that I assigned .

What I want to achieve is , when an item is checked , it will be displayed and when I clicked another item , the previous image will be overridden by the new item that was checked .

I assigned an ID and class in the image and here is my JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  
$(function() {
  $('.decalcheckbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change",function() { 
    var checkbox = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var checkboxremovespace = checkbox.replace(/ /g, "_")
$('#decal_'+ checkboxremovespace).toggle(this.checked); 
  }).change(
  ); // trigger the change
});

});
```

Sorry for my English but I hope I explained what I want to say .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I just made some modification on my code as follows .

Hopefully someone can shed some light .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  
$(function() {
  $('.decalcheckbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change",function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#bento_preview_item").hide();
    }
    else{
      $("#bento_preview_item").show();
    }
    var checkbox = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var checkboxremovespace = checkbox.replace(/ /g, "_")
$('#decal_'+ checkboxremovespace).toggle(this.checked); 
  }).change(
  ); // trigger the change
});

});
```

Thanks .